# Anybody familiar with the Shoretel database?

Tags: mysql, sql, voip, shoretel

I have a copy of the local db from our old shoretel voip system... which is no longer in service.
I've been tasked with trying to locate information pertaining to calls to and from specific numbers over the past year or so.

Wondering if anybody is familiar with the schema of this database and which tables I might be able to query to find call info. I had done some investigation and read that there should be a "calls" table, but there is not. None of the tables are named in such a way that it sounds like the correct table for call transactions.

Any info is helpful, thank you

Comment: You may find this google.com search helpful.  shorewarecdr tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database you search for is named `shorewarecdr` (from CDR - Call Detail Record). It should have tables `call`, `connect` and few other. Check there.

Comment: Thanks, after some more research I was able to determine that the shoreware cdr database is served from port 4309- I was looking in the shoretel configuration database which is on port 4308.